# Copy and name a worksheet with version number in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy from a master template and rename the copy in Excel VBA.

I am trying to rename the first copy of the master to DATA 1 and then the next time the new sheet would be DATA 2.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim iThisMonth As Integer, iLastMonth As Integer
Dim datLastRun As Date
Dim rCheckCell As Range
Set rCheckCell = Sheets("master").Range("A5")
Set Target = Range("V16")

On Error Resume Next
datLastRun = CDate(rCheckCell.Value)
iLastMonth = Month(datLastRun)
On Error GoTo 0

If Target.Value = "yes" Then
    MsgBox "Call Peter"
    Call Peter
    rCheckCell.Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mmm/yy")
End If
End Sub
```

Macro Code

```vb
Sub Peter()

Sheets("Master").Visible = True
Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
NewPageName = Data1
ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.Name = NewPageName

End Sub
```

I want to copy and rename to DATA 1 when I have entered YES in cell V16 but then I want to rename MASTER to DATA 2 the next time YES is entered into cell V16.

Comment: What is the specific question you have? How to name the sheet? I'm guessing you would first need to check to see if `DATA 1` exists. If not, then name the sheet `DATA 1`. Else, name the sheet in increments (Split the sheet name and add 1)

Comment: so i have a master template called MASTER which i want to copy and rename to DATA 1 when i have entered YES in cell V16 but then i want it to rename MASTER to DATA 2 the next time YES is entered into Cell V16

Answer (score 1):

Create a basic function like below which will give you the next available name. For example, if there is a worksheet with the name `Data1` and `Data2`, then the below function will return `Data3`

```
Private Function NewDataName() As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim shtname As String
    
    Do
        '~~> Create a worksheet name
        shtname = "DATA" & i
        
        '~~> Check if we already have a worksheet with that name
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtname)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        '~~> If no worksheet with that name then return name
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            NewDataName = shtname
            Exit Do
        Else
            i = i + 1
            Set ws = Nothing
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

And the usage will be like

```
Sub Peter()
    Sheets("Master").Visible = True
    Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.Name = NewDataName
End Sub
```

Comment: This dont seem to work for me it just creates a copy of the master and gives an error

Comment: What error are you getting? The above code is tested :) Did you paste the function as well? If yes then put a breakpoint on `ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.Name = NewDataName` and see what value are you getting in  `NewDataName`

Comment: do i add this to what i have already or replace it ?

Comment: Thanks I have made it work now using bits of the code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function fxCopySheetName(ByVal pBook As String, ByVal pSheet As String, ByVal pName As String) As String
    With Workbooks(pBook)
        .Sheets(pSheet).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = pName
        fxCopySheetName = .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name
    End With
End Function
```